# extract value from JSON Array

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to extract value from a `JSon` Array. My above code displays the "response" in textview. I get the response as `[{"JsonOutput":"Er"}]` in the `textview` at present. I want to extract Er and set to `TextView`.

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvData1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);


        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,     OPERATION_NAME);
                    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();
                    propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                    propertyInfo.name = "eid";

                    edata =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    studentNo=edata.getText().toString();

                    request.addProperty(propertyInfo, studentNo);

                            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                            envelope.dotNet = true;

                            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                            HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);

                            try  {                    
                            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);                    
                            Object response = envelope.getResponse();                    
                            tvData1.setText(response.toString());

                           // Do here something to extract value (Er) from the key:value pair. 





                            }  catch (Exception exception)   {
                                          tvData1.setText(exception.toString());                    
                            }

                    tvData1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            }
        });



 }
}
```

Comment: You should not have Network request's on ui thread. `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.toString());
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.get(0);
String output = jsonObject.getString("JsonOutput");`

Comment: it is an JSON Array or only one JSON object???

Comment: @Amol Its a one JSON object

Comment: Use the JSONObject Class, pass the string to the contructor, then you will be able to access the fields. Look at: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Actually, when the root of the JSON is `[]`, you are dealing with a JSON array

Comment: so why you are creating JSON array for that.,.. create {"JsonOutput":"Er"} only and parse it

Comment: @AmolSawant96Kuli you don't know where the response comes from or who is responsible for building the response. It's no use commenting he'd better change it.

Comment: @Raghunandan. Perfect. Thanks buddy. Just one more help. How to consume DOT NET webservice within asynctask. I get some error when I tried to do this in asynctask. That's why I used strictmode.

Comment: Next time you ask a question, please make sure the code is formatted properly

Comment: @SomnathKanakDrishtiInfotech don't ask a new question in a comment. Instead just ask a new question. Better yet, don't, because there are already countless examples on how to use AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

get your `JSONObject` string with `"JsonOutput"`

```
try{            
    JSONArray root = new JSONArray(response);
    for (int i = 0; i < root.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject att = (JSONObject) root.getJSONObject(i);
        String ouput= att.getString("JsonOutput");
    }
}catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you get JSONArray

```
 JSONArray response = new JSONArray(envelope.getResponse().toString());
```

else if you get JSONObject

```
 JSONObject response = new JSONObject(envelope.getResponse().toString());
```

override your .toString() method if it is required.

now you can have `response[0].getString("JsonOutput")` in case of array and in case of object you can have `response.getString("JsonOutput")` And yes as someone mentioned in the comments don't have network calls on Main Thread.